# Track customers who left an order at shipping/payment/final stage

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout

Want to track the customers who have put everything they wanted in the basket. Went to check out and changed their mind. Tried googling, but could not find anything related to this topic. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look to the Magemonkey plugin, a plugin what is working with Mailchimp / Mandrill to send mail.

Have a look at -> [ebizmarts.com/blog/2013/03/increase-your-sales-with-magemonkeys-free-recover-abandoned-carts](http://ebizmarts.com/blog/2013/03/increase-your-sales-with-magemonkeys-free-recover-abandoned-carts)